# Unable to unregister twilo voice Token from IOS device

Tags: flutter, twilio, voice

### Twilit Multiple logins (Flutter Application)

I am not able to log out Twilio voice token in case of Multiple logins.

**Case:**

If a user logs in on an IOS device the case application works perfectly. Once the user logs in from another device and the user does not log out of the previous device ( and it is iOS Device) in this case, the user gets a call on both of his devices. I am able to stop getting a call on both of the devices if the user's first login device is Android.

**Why I am able to solve this issue if an initial log-in device is an Android?**

I am able to solve this on Android because I am able to locate a method that triggers after getting a push notification on a device. At this time I unregister the Twilio voice token from Android Device. In this case, it does not matter app is in the foreground or the background.

**Why I am not able to solve this issue if an initial log-in device is an iOS?**

In this case, I am not able to find out the method that is triggered while the iOS device gets a push notification from One Signal when an application is in the background. That’s why I am not able to call the Twilio voice unregister method. If the application is in the foreground I am able to solve the problem. In the case of background, I am not able to unregister twilo voice token.

**What I tried to solve this issue?**

1 If I am not able to call unregister method from the iOS device I can still call the same unregister method from the second device. Now I need to have the previous device's voice token and fcm token. I am able to get the previous device's voice(Twilio JWT TOKEN)  and fcm token from my backend Server. In this case, Twilio unregistered the second device instead of the previous Device. The problem is not solved.

2 Unable to find REST API of Twilio  from where My back server unregistered for Push Notification